# Equilibrium point of the euler-lagrange differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, euler-lagrange-equation, stability-theory

I have the differential equation:
$$M(q)\ddot{q}+C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q} = J(q)[K_p(t)e+K_d(t)\dot{e}]$$
that represents Euler-Lagrange dynamic of a closed-loop system including the control input law, where $q$ is the state and $e$ the error signal. How to find the equilibrium point of the equation?

UPDATE1:
The equation in the state space form $\dot{x}=f(x,u)$ where $x_1=q , x_2=\dot{q}$ is:
 $$\dot{x_1}=x_2$$
$$\dot{x_2}=M(x_1)^{-1}[-C(x_1,x_2)+J(x_1)u(t)]$$
where $u(t)$ the input law is
$$u(t)=K_p(t)e+K_d(t)\dot{e}$$
UPDATE2:
e is defined as $e=[e_x\:e_y]^T$ where $e_x=x-x_{ref}$ and so $e_y=y-y_{ref}$ 
where $x,y,x_{ref},y_{ref}$ are the outputs of the kinematic model and $q=[q_1\:q_2]^T$ is the generalized coordinates of the dynamic model.

To summerized this is equation of a 2DOF robotic arms where q represents the angles of joints and x,y the cartesian coordinate of the end-effector and it is controlled by Transpose Jacobian control law:

$$\tau=J(q)[K_p(t)e+K_d(t)\dot{e}]$$

In an article the author said that equilibrium point of the aforementioned closed-loop equation is the solution of:
$$K_p(t)e+K_d(t)\dot{e}=0$$

But I didn't catch why.

Comment: Try to write down the dynamics in state variable form $\dot{x}(t)=\textbf{f}(x)$, the equilibrium points are those where the vector field vanishes.

Comment: I have made some update

Comment: How is $e$ defined (i.e. what is your output)?

Comment: I have added some information

Comment: After reaching the equilibrium point, no actuation is needed so at this point $K_p e+K_d \dot e = 0$ and the dynamic model reamains at $M^{-1}(x_1^*)C(x_1^*, 0) = 0, x_2^* = 0$.

Comment: Thank all of you.